# how to add a remove button to file upload in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-component

i'm new in coding joomla components i'm coding my first component at all and starting my knowledge from 0 in PHP

in my component i have 4 file uploaders (3 for images/pdf/etc.. and 1 for videos) and i would like to add a button to remove the file in case the person doesn't want the file anymore

can help me in this ?

here's the code of the form page:

```
<div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('video'); ?></div>
            <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('video'); ?></div>
        </div>

            <?php if (!empty($this->item->video)) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(JUri::base() . 'components' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'com_product_manager' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'video' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->item->video, false);?>">[View File]</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="jform[video]" id="jform_video_hidden" value="<?php echo $this->item->video ?>" />                <input type="hidden" name="jform[ordering]" value="<?php echo $this->item->ordering; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="jform[state]" value="<?php echo $this->item->state; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="jform[checked_out]" value="<?php echo $this->item->checked_out; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="jform[checked_out_time]" value="<?php echo $this->item->checked_out_time; ?>" />
```

Any further information you need ask and i'll provide it

Comment: Just a small comment. You should provide all the information in the first place so that people don't have to ask (i.e. you should provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Many will not be bothered with your question if you leave it incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller file, you should add a function called deleteImage that will delete the image from the filesystem. In your layout file (your view's template, as in "default.php"), you should add a link next to each uploaded file that goes like this:

```
index.php?option=com_pressrelease&task=deleteImage&id=imageId
```